# Selecting row based on ID and then again based on cardinality of text box

Tags: php, mysql, sql, laravel, eloquent

My issue is I need to rank and group the following database like this Film -> Most used text.

So I have the table below that records userId, filmId and text related to a emotional response. What I want to do is take say film 52, and get the text that is used the most and second most, for example in this scenario there are 7 "texts" that are unique, and 2 that are used twice, "Beautiful" and "Ingenious" so I need to get Beautiful and Ingenious as a result for film 52. How can this be done in MYSQL or Laravel Eloquent? Thanks so much for any info
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declare a variable in a join, and increment it in your grouping query, but be sure to order by in the inner query or the rank will have no value. then select from the inner query where the rank is less than or equal to the desired rank.

```
SELECT FILMID, TEXT
FROM (
  SELECT FILMID, TEXT, COUNT(*), @r:=@r+1 AS RANK
  FROM filmReview
    JOIN (SELECT @r:=0) R
  GROUP BY FILMID, TEXT
  ORDER BY FILMID, COUNT(*) DESC, TEXT
  ) T
WHERE RANK <= 2
```

Check it out at [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a88c2/9).

Comment: Just checked and saw this post and it worked perfectly! thank you so much